Why is the code coverage missing for lines where inject() is used in functional ngrx effect?
I am working on an Angular project and using karma.js with jasmine to write and execute unit tests.
My problem is that if I want to unit test the functional ngrx effect without the TestBed, the coverage report reports the lines as uncovered where I inject the dependencies to my effect function.
I have created a dummy effect to demonstrate the issue.
Actions:
export const MyActions = createActionGroup({
  source: 'Dummy',
  events: {
    'Some action': emptyProps(),
  },
});

Effect:
export const dummy = createEffect(
  (actions$ = inject(Actions)) =>
    actions$.pipe(
      ofType(MyActions.someAction),
      tap(() => console.log('inject line is not covered :(')),
    ),
  { functional: true, dispatch: false },
);

Unit test:
  it('should run as an example', (done: DoneFn) => {
    const actionsMock$ = of(MyActions.someAction());

    dummy(actionsMock$).subscribe(() => {
      expect(true).toBe(true);
      done();
    });
  });

Coverage report as an image (shows in red that the line is not covered):

I have found that using the TestBed the mentioned issue can be avoided as stated in this github issue: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/3668#issuecomment-2093221356, but I would like to keep TestBed out of unit testing the ngrx effects for simplicity.

you are passing actions directly in dummy(actionsMock$) and obviuously default parameter isn't being built. if you wish this thing to be "covered" make a provider for Actions and TestBest.runInInjectionContext(dummy) for it to make use of di

When you do not provide an input value, only then the default value is used and covered.
You cannot use inject without TestBed.runInInjectionContext, so try this below code.
  it('should run as an example', (done: DoneFn) => {
    const actionsMock$ = of(MyActions.someAction());

    TestBed.runInInjectionContext(() => dummy()).subscribe(() => {
      expect(true).toBe(true);
      done();
    });
  });


So it looks like what I wanted to achieve is not possible, and I must provideMockActions(...) via the TestBed?
This example just looked so clean :) https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/testing#functional-effects

@kristof Yes but the coverage does not visit the default block hence the problem with this approach, you can write a single test case for runInInjectionContext just for covering the default values of a function
